# How to customise the default Laravel registration Controller

Tags: laravel

i have a database with  user table and the id is custom made using IDgenerator. and a second table that holds documents of a user which has a foreign key of user if
the set up is as below

```
table 1
user_id
name
email
profile-pic

table 2
id
user_id (Foreign Key)
document 1
document 2
document 3
```

when registering the user is supposed to insert all the fields

so my question is how do i achieve all this through editing the default registerController laravel comes with?

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using? did you install a pacakage to get this default registration/authentication setup?

Comment: yes i did, and its finally been solved

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
$user = $request->all();
$user['user_id'] = $unique_id;
event(new Registered($user = $this->create($user)));
```